# Off with ya meaning

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I am watching Django Unchained (2012) and there is a dialog between King Schultz and Speck Brothers where one of the Speck Brothers says:

-I do not care, No sale. Now, off with ya.

Could anyone help me find out exact meaning of the term "off with ya"?

Can I use it in a normal polite conversation with native speaker?

Comment: **- Antidote En**                                                                                             *off with you!*
***formal, not polite***                                                                                        – an expression used to tell someone to go away from somewhere quickly, usually because they are not wanted there                                                     — _Be off with you, wench!_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Off with ya*** is both idiomatic and dialect, meaning ***Go away***. Less dialect-ish, but still idiomatic, is ***Be off with you***. It's not considered crude/vulgar, the way ***f$$$ off*** would be, but is definitely borderline rude, and certainly not polite.

[Urban Dictionary's definition of ***Be off with you***](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Be%20off%20with%20you) is better, in my opinion, than [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-with-you) or [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_off_with_you).

Comment: I agree, its literal meaning is not polite. That said, I've heard it used affectionately/jokingly, which is *not* impolite in the right context, more often than I've heard it used seriously. English learners should probably avoid using it, but also probably should not take offense if an otherwise-friendly native speaker says it to them.

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic AmE expression

***[off with you!](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-with-you)*** in American

> go away! depart!

Collins Dictionary

***[Ya](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ya)*** (informal)

> non-standard spelling of you or your, used to represent a pronunciation
>
> - ‘see ya later

ODO

Comment: Is it polite? or impolite? Can I use it with my students?

Comment: I’d say informally impolite.

Answer (score 0):

It just means "go away."  As in, I don't want what you are selling, now go away.

Comment: Is it polite? or impolite?

Comment: @G.T. It’s formal and not polite.